# Customising YoutubePlayer in android using Youtube API 3

Tags: java, android, youtube-data-api

I need to customize youtube player according to some point.

1. I need to remove Youtube Button from `DEFAULT` style.

   player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
   player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.MINIMAL);

[image]

2.I customized it like below image.

[image]

But according to the second image **I am not getting quality choosing option** as i am getting in basic one.

I looked for it everywhere but i am not getting it. With using iframe API it can be done in JavaScript. But for android i am not getting it. using `CHROMELESS` Style in youtube Player.

```
player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);
```

Thanks in adavance.

Comment: AFAIK youtube player api does not currently support quality change through code.

Comment: So how can i do this in android ? Is there any way ?

Comment: A WebView perhaps? You'd need to do lots of customizing.

Comment: If I am using webview then I cannot remove youtube button as I have explained in my first point.

Comment: Well you're going to have to give one thing up!

Comment: It's quite easy to customize the web player using a WebView. I've done it in my library: https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/Android-YouTube-Player

As Abbas says, quality change is not supported. A method to do that is available in the YouTube IFrame API but, from what i've found, it's not reliable at all.